# Laravel running function from button in blade

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-routing

I am having an issue getting a button in a blade file to properly run a function in a controller, when i click the button i get a methodnotallowedexception and have not been able to figure out what is not setup correctly

To my knowledge this is written like another button i have for a different blade and controller, unless i am overlooking something, which is why i am here. if you need other code let me know.

first my routes:

```
Route::post('/viewPatient/{user}/discharge', 'PatientController@discharge')->name('patients.discharge');
Route::post('/viewPatient/{user}/reAdmitt', 'PatientController@reAdmitt')->name('patients.reAdmitt');  
Route::post('/viewPatient/{user}/reAdmitted', 'PatientController@reAdmitted')->name('patients.reAdmitted');
```

next the controller functions

```
public function discharge(User $user)
    {
        $user->discharged = true;
        $user->discharged_date = now();
        $user->current_facility_id = null;
        $user->save();
        // find all the users documents that are not historical
        $documents = Document::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('historical', false)->get();
        // mark them all as historical
        foreach($documents as $document){
            $document->historical = true;
            $document->save();
        }

        return $this->index(); 
    }

    public function reAdmitt(User $user)
    {
        $user->discharged = false;
        $user->readmitting = true;
        $user->reAdmission_start = now();
        $user->save();

        return $this->index(); 
    }

    public function reAdmitted(User $user)
    {
        $user->discharged = false;
        $user->readmitting = false;
        $user->reAdmitted_on = now();
        $user->save();

        return $this->index(); 
    }
```

and finally the buttons themselves

```
<button><a href="{{route('patients.reAdmitt', $user)}}">Readmitt Patient</a></button>
<button><a href="{{route('patients.reAdmitted', $user)}}">Patient Signed reAdmission</a></button>
<button><a href="{{route('patients.discharge', $user)}}">Discharge Patient</a></button>
```

the expected result is that it should run the function and update the database, i know the function to discharge works because i accidentally changed the route to a get and it ran when the page loaded and marked one of the patients as discharged.

Comment: The simple button will trigger a `GET` request but you defined your route as a `POST` request - `Route::post(...`. The general rule of thumb is that if the action is going to be destructive (Ie. CrUD) then it should be a post request. So I'd change your button to be an actual form with hidden fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not submitting any form. So you don't need to use post routes. `<a>` tag is for get routes. So change your routes as

```
Route::get('/viewPatient/{user}/discharge', 'PatientController@discharge')->name('patients.discharge');
Route::get('/viewPatient/{user}/reAdmitt', 'PatientController@reAdmitt')->name('patients.reAdmitt');  
Route::get('/viewPatient/{user}/reAdmitted', 'PatientController@reAdmitted')->name('patients.reAdmitted')
```

;